# Displaying form with jquery

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, jquery

My current code will hide an `example` form and then will display data taken from other page via json into `confirm` div.

```
...other codes

},function(data){
if (data.response==1) {
    $('#example').delay(500).fadeOut();
    $('#confirm').show().html("<form>First name: <input type=\"text\" name=\"name\" value=\" "+ data.name +"  \"><br>Email: <input type=\"text\" name=\"email\" value=\" "+ data.email +" \"></form>"); 
}

...other codes

     <div id="confirm" style="background-color:#FF7800; padding-left:20px; color: white;"></div>
```

My question is it possible to show/trigger other form and display my data instead of displaying my data inside `html()` in `#confirm` id? I think I get the idea how to trigger a hidden form but how do I populated my data inside it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Yes, wrap them in DIV's (or assign the form an ID):

HTML:

```
<div id="exampleForm">
  <form> [.. do form here ..] </form>
</div>

<div id="realForm" style="display:none">
  <form> [.. do form here ..] </form>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(function() {
  $("#exampleForm").fadeOut();
  $("#realForm").fadeIn();
});
```

Comment: Hi, how do I populated the new form with my data? Let's say I have `data.name` and `data.email`. I need to populate it inside `value` attribute. How to achieve this? Thanks for your reply :)